# Unable to download Go packages from GitHub

Tags: go, github, go-github

I'm getting below error while downloading.

**go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql: module github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/@v/list": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

**Go version - 1.13/1.15(tried both)**
**OS - Ubuntu 18
Tried update ca-certificates as well**

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I meant adding much much more information to your question: this is the point of my answer and my comments: there is *a lot* we did not know about your environment, which would help other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Check first the context in which this error pops up:

- `go version`
- execution environment (shell).

For instance, this error pops up during Docker build instance, where the Dockerfile uses an image without certificates installed, as in [`golang/go` issue 35702](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35702#issuecomment-557632968).
Said Dockerfile would need:

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: Go version- go version go1.15.6 linux/amd64
I'm running this as a standalone application.

Comment: @alokrai Then it seems the certificates are not installed on your OS. Which OS this is? Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. If you're aware then can you let me know the steps for installing the certificates. Thanks!!

Comment: @alokrai Try `sudo update-ca-certificates`

Comment: @alokrai are you running this in a corporate network, via a captive portal, or in some other situation where there is a third party man-in-the-middling your TLS connections? Can you check what `openssl s_client -connect github.com:443` returns?

Comment: Yes I'm using this in a corporate network. That Command returns below response:
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "GitHub, Inc.", CN = github.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=Digi

Comment: @alokrai OK. Can you add all that in your question (OS, go version, coprporate network, openssl answer)?